# Jquery not working properly?

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble with jquery.
At the end of my page, before closing the `</body>` tag, I have included the jquery cdn:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then at the top, in the `<head>`, I included my own little code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#liked').click(function() {
                $('#changed').addClass('likeClicked');
            });
        });
</script>
```

This is affecting the following:

```
<button id='changed' class="like">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" id='liked' style="font-size:2.0em;"></span>
</button>
```

However, the code isn't working. (CSS below). I've tried changing the jquery to hover instead of click, to different classes or elements instead of id's. I don't know what i'm doing wrong.. any idea? Thanks.

```
.like {
-webkit-appearance: none;
outline: none;
border: 0;
background: transparent;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
transition-duration: 0.2s;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

.likeClicked {
color: #00bc0e;
}
```

Comment: `jquery.min.js` should come before your script block.

Comment: Put the CDN in the HEAD tag, not at the end of page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order of loading is important. Your code is dependent on the jQuery library so the library needs to load before your code.

If you look in your browser console you will currently see error `$ is not defined`. This will stop all further script execution in the page

Comment: I must have spent hours with this. Thank you so much, it worked, Quick question, is there any disadvantage to adding the jquery cdn at the head instead of at the bottom of the page? I remember learning that some time ago that it sped up loading time.

Comment: best practices suggest putting scripts in bottom of body for faster loading of the content. In many cases you won't notice a lot of difference depending on how much script/content there is.

Comment: "This will stop all further script execution in the page" — Only in that script element.